# Updating a set of tables using Entity Framework & Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have code where I need to update a master table's row and then update a few rows of another table, and then save the changes to the database.

My question is: can I update the entity and then update the entities to the database?

Code example:

```
Master master = new Master();
List<Slave> lstSlave = new List<Slave>();

master = _master.Table.Where(x => x.Id == Id || x.status != "deleted").FirstOrDefault();
master.Status = Fixed;

lstSlave = _slave.Table.Where(x => x.masterId == Id || x.status != "deleted").ToList();

foreach(Slave slave in lstSlave)
{
   slave.Status = Fixed;
   _slave.Update(slave)
   db.SaveChanges();
}

_master.Update(master)

db.SaveChanges();
```

`db` here is the `object Context`. the doubt here is that weather I have to save the changes each time the slave is updated.

Or can I save the changes at the end after updating the master too (whole entity)

The table is not getting updated when I tried saving changes the second way...

Please don't mind if the question seems silly (rookie here)...

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It should work. Is the Master's status updated correctly in both scenarios?

Comment: master status is all fine but the list seems to be missing something

Comment: Well, a good start could be to show what happens inside the `Update` methods. There's probably some context involved, but is it the same context as the one that saves changes?

Comment: @GertArnold I am using only one context. Am I doing it right? Can we update all the tables in the context and then write to the table?